# Sorting of array by another (not related) array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays of the same length. First array is static with data of such format
 `a = [['q', 10], ['s', 20], ['z', 40], ['d', 15]]` and another array `b = [1, 0, 0, 1]`. So `['q', 10]` in mind is related to `1`, `['s', 20]` - to `0`, `['z', 40]` to `0`, `['d', 15]` to `1`.
Then I do some sorting of the first array and receive, for example, `a = [['d', 15], ['s', 20], ['q', 10], ['z', 40]]`. So in what way can I change second array to receive `b = [1, 0, 1, 0]`?

Important. It is not possible to add/change any data in first array.

Comment: look up a suitable sorting algorithm and implement it taking into account that you need to rearrange both arrays.

Comment: What do you mean, "it is not possible" to change the first array?  What if you change it before sorting and then change it back?

Comment: What if you change it before sorting and then change it back?
ok, such way is possible :)

Comment: I don't know why you'd need to do this, why not put the arrays togther eg. [['q', 10, 1], ['s', 20, 0], ['z', 40, 0], ['d', 15, 1]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change the first array temporarily, you can do this:

1. Augment the first array with an index value for each element:

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
     a[i] = { value: a[i], index: i };
   }
   ```
2. Sort the array.  If your sort function is "compare", then you can do it like this:

   ```
   a.sort(function(e1, e2) {
     return compare(e1.value, e2.value);
   });
   ```
3. Now you can make a new "b" by arranging it according to the indexes:

   ```
   var newB = [];
   for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
     newB[i] = b[a[i].index];
   b = newB;
   ```
4. Now restore the values of "a":

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
     a[i] = a[i].value;
   ```

Comment: or you can just create a property on each element of the original array `a` that holds the corresponding value from the original array `b`.

Comment: @akonsu yes, that'd work, unless the original array elements are numbers or strings.  Also, even if they're objects, that's risky because there might be a name collision. Of course, in the (common) case where one has complete knowledge of the nature of the array values, those may not be problems to worry about.

Comment: thanx. i used your idea. one correction, in step 1 'index' must be so: index: b[i]. and I also combined steps 3 and 4

Answer (score 1):

You can keep an array of the return values of the first sort..

```
var c = [];
var newa = a.sort(function(a,b){
    var ret = a[1] - b[1];// whatever you're sorting on
    c.push(ret); // save return value
    return ret;
});
```

Then do the same with the second sort.

```
// go through and sort b the same way
var i=0;
var newb = b.sort(function(){
   return c[i++];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function to use in sorting that will swap elements in both arrays at the same time,

```
function swap(array1,array2,a,b) {
  temp = array1[a];
  array1[a] = array1[b];
  array1[b] = temp;
  temp = array2[a];
  array2[a] = array2[b];
  array2[b] = temp;
}
```

So then you can do

```
a = [0,1,2,3];
b = [0,1,2,3];
swap(a,b,0,1);
```

And you'll end up with

```
a: [1,0,2,3];
b: [1,0,2,3];
```

Otherwise, if you're actually looking to sort one array in ascending or descending order and have the other array be sorted according to how the first was sorted, check out php.js's array_multisort here: http://phpjs.org/functions/array_multisort/

And for some extra documentation on array_multisort, http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php